# How to print the literal string of '&#32' at the output of my transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to do a transformation xsl to xsl document using namespace-alias. I face problem with passing literal value of an ASCII character in the output.

This is the line I have in the input **xsl**:

```
<xslAlt:variable name="result" select="translate({$var-name},'&#32;','&#160;')"/>
```

This is what I get as an output:

```
<xsl:variable name="result" select="translate(test-case-1-return,' ',' ')"/>
```

And this is the output I dream of:

```
<xsl:variable name="result" select="translate(test-case-1-return,'&#32;','&#160;')"/>
```

In other words I don't want `'&#32;','&#160;'` expanded at the output. I want them as they are in the input document.

**Thank you!**

**EDITION:** The processor I am using in this transformation is Saxon (XSLT 2.0)

**EDITION:**
I tried this:

```
<xsl:character-map name="a">
   <xsl:output-character character="&#32;" string="&#32;"/>
   <xsl:output-character character="&#160;" string="&#160;"/>
</xsl:character-map>
<xsl:output indent="yes" use-character-maps="a"/>

<xslAlt:variable name="result" select="translate({$var-name}, '&#32;', '&#160;')"/>
```

But didn't work either. I don't get the literal string `&#32;"` instead I get an empty spaces:

```
<xsl:variable name="result" select="translate(test-case-1-return,  ,  )"/>
```

as a result.

I tried the transformation with another processor namely Xalan 1.0. and everything worked as I expected. I don't understand why it doesn't work that way with Saxon. You would say: Then why aren't you using Xalan processor? The answer is: There is no xslt 2.0 support and many functions doesn't work with that processor.

Comment: Try to escape the ampersands by using `&amp;` instead, like `'&amp;#32;'` and `'&amp;#160;'`

Comment: In this case I get: 

    <xsl:variable name="result" select="translate(test-case-1-return,&amp;#32;,&amp;#160;)"/>

Comment: @har07 It works that way. Although with another processor (Xalan). I suspect that the IDE I am using, uses an obsolete version of Saxon processor. The IDE is Exchange XML Editor version 3.3.01.

Answer (score 2):

Do you use an XSLT 2.0 processor? In that case you could use a character map, see http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#character-maps for the syntax and examples.

You set up the mapping as

```
<xsl:character-map name="a">
   <xsl:output-character character="&#32;" string="&amp;#32;"/>
   <xsl:output-character character="&#160;" string="&amp;#160;"/>
</xsl:character-map>
<xsl:output indent="yes" use-character-maps="a"/>
```

A short sample is at http://xsltransform.net/6r5Gh2M.

Comment: Yes but the stylesheet version is 1.0

Comment: If you use an XSLT 2.0 processor then character maps are supported even with a version 1.0 stylesheet.

Comment: Thank you. Some examples would be very useful.

Comment: I have edited my answer and added a link to the spec which also has examples.

Comment: Thank you for the link with the examples but didn't work in my case.

Comment: I have edited the answer and shown how to adapt your sample. The replacement the character is mapped to needs to escape the ampersand.

Comment: Ouch!!! It is a processor bug! I tried it with Xalan and it works with only &amp; prefix. Thank you all.

Comment: What is a processor bug? Xalan is an XSLT 1.0 processor so it does not support character maps at all.

Comment: I wasn't using char map technique at all. The &amp; did the job so this line **({$var-name},'&amp;#32;','&amp;#160;')**  completely did what I wanted BUT using another processor (xalan). See my original post edited for more info.

Comment: Your code works. The problem is that every space encountered in my code is transformed into &#32; at the output. I want this char map to work only for a part of my code.